# JavaScript: Changing Language Without Page Reload

Tags: javascript

I am implementing multilingual support into my webpage. I would like to minimize the page blinking caused from page reload, and I came to the idea to change page language without forcing the whole page to reload. To achieve this, the only possible way that comes to my mind is with the use of JavaScript:

1. I dynamically load appropriate language .js file with appropriate translations
2. I manually go through every text object on the page and update it by re-sending the appropriate new text value

To provide you with example code, I paste a code that will update just submit buttons. On the language change, I call a function that loads appropriate .js language file dynamically.

```
var fileRef = LoadJsCssFile("Language/svk.js", "js", UpdateLanguage);
```

After the language .js file is fully loaded, I call the function that updates every element containing text on the webpage:

```
function UpdateLanguage()
{
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("submit_button");
    for (buttonID in buttons)
    {           
            buttons[buttonID].innerHTML = lang.SUBMIT;
    }                   
};
```

Manually updating every text object in the webpage is complex and error prone. As I am not very experienced with JavaScript yet, I was thinking, if there is a way to simply refresh the all key elements in the webpage with one JavaScript command without casing the webpage blink?

If you have any other idea, how to effectively implement language change without page blink, I am interested to know. :-)

Comment: It would be better to use AJAX to simply load the new page and then replace the HTML in the current document body.

Comment: You'll probably want to replace the text sentence-by-sentence, rather than using one word as a unit, as translations are more often about the whole context of the sentence rather than just replacing individual words - otherwise the meaning can be lost.

Comment: @mattb Otherwise, the meaning *will* be lost.

Comment: also are your users really changing their language setting all that often for it to be worth the effort to handle it without reloading the page from the server? Most users will rarely change a language more than once, if ever.

Comment: Are you using HTML5 and jQuery? or what exactly?

Comment: @diolemo: +1 - Hi Diolemo. Thank you for the idea. I did not consider Ajax, and it looks interesting. I might use php to generate new blocks of text which looks interesting. However, with AJAX, if the site is busy, or server is slow, there can be delay in response, is that correct? Say, this webpage, stackoverflow.com, reacts by various text buttons, messages, etc.. i would say, it is rather JavaScript than AJAX.

Comment: @mattb: Hi Matt, surely, I plan to minimize the work needed. I do not replace word by word, but there are situations, where I have to replace only one word: menu items, button text. Where are blocks of text, I replace whole blocks.

Comment: Don't use for..in, use a for loop, otherwise you will be accessing enumerable properties of the HTMLCollection object that are't elements (e.g. length, item) and may do strange things if you try to set their innerHTML property. If you're using input elements as submit buttons, change their value property, not their innerHTML.

Comment: @mattb: good point, yes, that is correct. The users mostly use the language change button only once. Well, this came to my mind as an idea worth of trying, and an experiment, when I will learn something new. I agree that my solution is complicated, therefore, I hoped, I can apply for example .refresh() property on every element, and every elment will update itself easily.

Comment: @Zuul: I do not use any library. I use HTML5 but this can be done with any HTML if I am correct. And no JavaScript library is needed for this, in my opinion.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori You should just reload the entire page (either with AJAX or normally). Trying to replace every element is a bad idea. Having every language sent to the client (so you can change it client side) is also a bad idea (wastes bandwidth and causes slower loading).

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori I have never seen a professional site change the language in the way you are asking about.

Comment: @RobG: hi and +1. Thank you for your valuable comments. I am going to implement them now. for some reason .value() property did not work for me. I use `<a>` anchor elements to represent buttons. Maybe I did something wrong. I will try again.

Comment: @diolemo: yes, I understand your arguments. Maybe, I can protect myself saying, that I dynamically load only that JavaScript file, that is chosen by the user, during the application run.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori You are still having to load a file from the server so you might as well just reload the current page (with AJAX if you want to reduce flicker). There is no reason to change the language of each element (it will be a pain to maintain too).

Comment: @diolemo: AJAX is very good idea. I will get into it a bit deeper into it, to consider, how to use it to change the language. Basically, I wish to develop a web application, that will have very solid and stable feeling with fast responses.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori—it is normal to use a button to submit a form so that it is independent of javascript. If you are using a link (which is less robust and not intuitive for users)then change the innerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on my own:

1. I prepare several javascript language files containing strings per every keyword
2. On language selection button, I import appropriate language file for the language I wish to use
3. I manually update every text on the webpage through javascript.

The above solution is suitable for smaller sites. for large ones, that would be a lot of work, to update every single text string through javascript.